# Need help coming up with best structure for declaring/populating many arrays of XYZ data

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, data-structures

This is likely a simple concept for those who have worked with VB/VS for a while. I am plotting XY-style data on a scatter plot. Each set of data (Scan) has three columns of double precision data points: Potential, Current, and Time, not necessarily in that order. Each set contains up to 2000 points.

A typical Scan looks like this:

Potential | Current | Time

---

V1        |  i1     | t1

V2        |  i2     | t2

...

V n       |  i n    | t n

I already have a structure implemented to read the files, determine the order the fields are in, and then parse the data into an array in the correct order. I need to be able to plot these points in different ways, e.g. Potential vs. Time or Current vs Time or Current vs. Potential.

The problem is, I need many of these arrays (I am thinking no more than 12), and I am not sure arrays are the best way to store this data. I am looking into DataTables and DataSets but these seem more for databases rather than simple double numbers (and I don't quite understand how to use them). I just need a way to store XYZ data that I can *perform operations on*, read and plot.

Thank you for your input!

Comment: One thing you could do is create your own "Battery" object. Each object would have an array of Potential, Current, and Time, and then you could have an Array of your "Battery" Objects. For plotting I'd recommend using the simple VB.Net Chart object (I can help with that)

Comment: a collection of list of XYZ points.  If you wrote a collection class, it might be able serve up the desired list (hard to tell the hierarchy)

Comment: I should probably clarify the heirarchy. Each data set (let's call them Scans: Scan1, Scan2 etc.) has three columns. Each column contains up to 2000 values, and each row represents a point where time, current and potential were measured. So for example, Scan1 would look like this:[this does not want to format properly]

And I need a bunch of those for Scan 2, 3 and so on. I would just make the charts right from the files, but I need to be able to do mathematical operations on them.

Comment: I would have a class to store X, Y, Z - no depending on an order in an array to keep the data straight.  Then a `List(Of XYZ)` which has the 2000 I am working with.  Then, a `XYZCollection` which stores the varietals ("the 12").  When I need one, something like `myList = XYZSets.GetData(someindicator)`.  I might even make the XYZ List a collection class with meta data like `Name` so there is never a doubt which data set my code is using.  Much of your description is procedural sounding rather than OO

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for. And yes, this is for a program to simulate, display and manipulate electrochemical data, so it is quite concrete. I will play around with this and see if I can get it to do what I need. Thank you!

Comment: Why is this tagged `d`?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I don't know... It's not showing up in my tag list either when I view this thread or when I edit it. I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to use a structure with the basic data then some generic lists to contain the data. it's type safe. fairly resource neutral, and keeps all the objects inside one object.

I tend to wrap the generic like this to simplify passing the top level data object to methods.

```
    ' single data item.
    Structure pointData
        Public voltage As Double
        Public current As Double
        Public time As Double
        ' place point specific  helper code here. such as this routine that may assist with generic graphing of 2 of the items by number.
        Public Function ValueByIndex(index As Integer) As Double
            Select Case index
                Case 0
                    Return voltage
                Case 1
                    Return current
                Case 2
                    Return time
                Case Else
                    Throw New Exception("Unsupported Index " & index)
            End Select
        End Function
    End Structure

    Public Class ScanData
        Inherits List(Of List(Of pointData))
        'put top level helper code you want here...
    End Class

    Private Sub test()
        Dim scans As New ScanData
        For iQ As Integer = 0 To 5 ' building some scan lists... your code here to populate.
            scans.Add(New List(Of pointData))
        Next
        'populate a specific scan with a single item.
        scans(0).Add(New pointData() With {.voltage = 4, .current = 6, .time = 8})
        'Access a single value from scan 0 item 4 for voltage
        Dim v As Double = scans(0)(4).voltage
        Dim v2 As Double = scans(0)(4).ValueByIndex(0) ' same as previous line but allows to get a series fo values by an index number

    End Sub
```

Comment: Just played around with this for a bit and yes, this perfectly solves my issue. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Your class could be like this:

```
Public Class Battery
    Private _voltage As Double()
    Private _current As Double()
    Private _time As Double()

    'Constructor
    Public Sub New(current, time, voltage)
        _current = current
        _time = time
        _voltage = voltage
    End Sub
    'Properties (like getters and setters)
    Property voltage As Double()
        Get
            Return _voltage
        End Get
        Set(value As Double())
            _voltage = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property current As Double()
        Get
            Return _current
        End Get
        Set(value As Double())
            _current = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property time As Double()
        Get
            Return _time
        End Get
        Set(value As Double())
            _time = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And then whenever you want to plot (assuming you have a Battery called bat, and a chart called Chart1)

`Chart1.ChartAreas(0).Series.Add("Series Name")`

`Chart1.ChartAreas(0).Series("Series Name").Points.DataBindXY(bat.voltage, bat.current)`

Comment: Perhaps I'm not savvy enough to see it, but I need to have all the points accessible simultaneously. For instance, Scan1 data point #1056 is (potential1056, current1056, time1056) and I need to subtract that from Scan6 data point #1056(potential1056, current1056, time1056). I am not seeing how the structure you posted does that.

Comment: If I'm seeing that correctly, you'd do: `ArrayOfBatteries(1).Voltage(1056) - ArrayOfBatteries(6).Voltage(1056)`, assuming you have an array of battery objects (as suggested). I'm saying battery but I guess they're called "Scan"

Comment: @MaxBessey Does that make sense? You could also define a function to subtract two Battery objects, or perform other operations.

Comment: Each Scan is a graph consisting of 2000 EIT (potential, current, time) points. It seems your batteries would then be be points, and the Scan would be the array. Am I getting that right? Also, when you say 'ArrayofBatteries(1)', where is that number one being declared and stored?